# android scheme loads but doesn't display activity when called from some devices

Tags: android, android-activity

i'm trying to run my app activity from browser.on one device it works like a charm, but on the other one it seems to go in the onCreate method but doesn't show up on screen.

my activity in manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name="unison.activities.FinalPageActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="payresponce" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

my activity:

```
public class FinalPageActivity extends Activity{

    private MessageView main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main = new MessageView(this, null);
        setContentView(main);
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        String status = data.getQueryParameter("status");
        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) finish();
        Toast.makeText(this,data.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Utils.log(data.toString());
    }
}
```

toast shows on screen and so does the log in logcat.. but the activity is not displayed

UPDATE:
 so turns out it was a completely different problem
i called finish so that it would go to the last activity from my app but it returned to browser.. i think it's the problem of the device and how it's keeping the activity stack.. any ideas how to go to my apps activity by calling finish()?

UPDATE2: 
i figured out then on some devices browser launches my app in its own task so when i call finish it goes back to browser not my apps last activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i finally found the solution. 
i added android:launchMode:"singleTask" to my activity attributes which made the activity start in my app's task or new one if mine was not present.

Answer (score 0):

You need a layout xml called `main.xml` in your layout resources file and:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: i have called it with a custom view

Comment: it's an old project and rewriting it is a lot of trouble so i'm just going with it..